# Force TLS 1.2 system wide for all applications?

Tags: linux, security, openssl, ssl

The organization I work for has lots of servers that run Linux.

We have recently been tasked with ensuring TLS 1.2 is used for all outbound connections for all our apps, regardless of the development platform our apps are written in, which varies quite a bit (Ruby/Node/Java/PHP)

**Is there a way at the system level to force everything to use TLS 1.2?**

Comment: I'm tempted to say "no", barring a search & fix mission to find every installed instance of an SSL app/library. 3rd-party apps may bring their own copies of openSSL.

Comment: Yeah it seems like everything I read on this suggests doing it on an app by app basis, and pretty much implied that it had to be done that way. I thought I'd ask to make sure we're not missing it at some higher level. Thanks!

Comment: you may want some sort of network analysis tool so you can at least detect when something is using unacceptable TLS (wireshark and filter on "ssl" would be a slow way...)

Comment: TLS can appear where you less expect it, including in RADIUS servers...do not forget the web servers too.

Comment: Why not IPSec your whole LAN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System wide? No, because there is no centralised TLS configuration on Linux (intentionally), and on top of that you probably have at least two TLS implementations on each system (OpenSSL or LibreSSL for certain, and most likely GnuTLS as well).

Auditing everything is unfortunately the only real option here.  However, once you've audited things for a given development platform, it should become really easy to check other applications on that platform (because you now know what a working connection setup sequence looks like).

Comment: And maybe NSS. And maybe Java (and maybe BC). And ...?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Actually, probably NSS, as that's what RPM uses.  Beyond that you also potentially have axTLS, mbedTLS (previously PolarSSL), Bouncy Castle (which I've not seen much use of myself), JSSE (Java's 'official' implementation), and the Erlang/OTP implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Considering a particular connection to a specific service, you could probably setup something to ensure anything below TLSv1.2 is rejected.

But you can't do this on a system-wide level. It just does not apply in generic systems (desktops, servers, etc). Each piece of code that connects to a TLS service can use one of several shared libraries on the system, can use its own shared library, can use statically linked or compiled in code, etc.

However if you are also tasked with ensuring that your servers will only accept TLSv1.2 connections, then you can certainly do that since you control all your service endpoints - normally web servers:

- https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/